# Inconsistent floats with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a couple prefabs I'm using to randomly generate a "room", but the same code is resulting in inconsistent widths:

[image: Odd widths]

The top (northWall) should be the same width as the bottom (southWall) but it's obviously 3 times the size.

Here is the "Room" prefab which instantiates the other "Wall" prefabs (they're all basically just Quads at this point).

```
public float length;
public float width;
public float wallDepth;

public Transform northWall;
public Transform southWall;

void Start () {
    length          = Random.Range (5.0f, 25.0f);
    width           = Random.Range (5.0f, 25.0f);
    wallDepth       = 2.0f;

    transform.localScale = new Vector3 (width, length, 0.0f);

    Instantiate (northWall, new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y + (transform.localScale.y / 2) + (wallDepth / 2), 10.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    northWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (width, wallDepth, 10.0f);

    Instantiate (southWall, new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y - (transform.localScale.y / 2) - (wallDepth / 2), 10.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    southWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (width, wallDepth, 10.0f);

}
```

Am I going crazy? Is it just late and I'm missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you set northwall and southwall to be in the inspector?

Comment: I've just dragged a Wall prefab to each of them. Wall is a quad with a box collider.

Comment: Then what are the specs of that inside the inspector?

Comment: They have no specs, they're a default quad whose position and scale are set to the same random floats (as per the code above). But as you can see the southWall is correct and the northWall is not. They're exactly the same prefab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. I think it's due to the fact that I was using the same prefab for each of the four walls. I made a function which returns a clone of the prefab and reassigns it to the original quad. This way the scale and position transforms apply only to the copied version of the quad:

```
GameObject buildWall (GameObject source, float width, float length, float x, float y, float z) {
    GameObject clone = Instantiate (source) as GameObject;

        clone.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (width, length, 0.0f);
        clone.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (x, y, z);

    return clone;
}
```

And instantiation now looks like this:

```
northWall = buildWall (northWall, width, wallDepth, transform.localPosition.x, transform.localPosition.y + (transform.localScale.y / 2) + (wallDepth / 2), 10.0f);
```

I don't know if this is the most effective (or even correct) way to go about doing this, but it seems to work for now.